# Put an icon between the two divs

Tags: html, css, icons

I want to put an icon (or png image) between two divs as in this image. (Green down icon) But I don't know how can i do this. Could you tell me how can i do or could you give me a link about this topic. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Please share some code you already have. We can help you update the code to get where you need to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use position absolute for the image.

Look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/ux8dgkpt/2/

```
.icon{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position: absolute;
    margin:-25px 0 0 -25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get a div which is '**position: absolute;**'. You move it with '**top**', '**bottom**' (count from next 'position: relative;' parent) or '**margin-top**'. Then you include another div tag in the div tag you edit. This should be '**position: relative;**' and '**margin: auto;**'. And now include your '**img**' tag.

Preview

```
<div style=background-image:url(); position: relative;">
 <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 25px;>
  <div style=margin: auto;>
   <img src="image.png" height=50">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

bol şans kardeşim, sorun varsa yardım ederim.